# In mathematics, what is meant by induction?

Tags: algorithms, induction, recursive-algorithms

I was going through [MIT video lectures on "Introduction to Algorithms "](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-046j-introduction-to-algorithms-sma-5503-fall-2005/video-lectures/lecture-2-asymptotic-notation-recurrences-substitution-master-method/) . In order to solve **recurrences by substitution** the professor says that we can solve them by *induction*.

What is actually the principle behind induction?

Comment: The Wikipedia article on this topic can be useful to read: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most basic principle is this:

> For any proposition P, which is a function from the natural numbers (1,2,...) to a boolean, if:
>
> - P(n) $\Rightarrow$ P(n+1) for all n, and
> - P(1)
>
> then P(n) for every n.

That is, if you can prove the base case P(1), and you can prove the implication P(n) $\Rightarrow$ P(n+1) for every n, then you have proved that P holds for all natural numbers.

Comment: what exactly you mean by "which is a function from the natural numbers (1,2,...) to a boolean," ..I am specifically confused with "to a boolean" part.

Comment: I mean that each P(n) is either true or false. Sorry, I assumed you were studying computer science so I phrased it in computer science language.

Comment: And ⇒ means holds good ?

Comment: The $\Rightarrow$ means "if ... then" in the sense of "if P(n) is true, then P(n+1) is true".

Answer (score 1):

Mathematical induction, strictly speaking, isn't a form of inductive reasoning. Indeed, it really isn't inductive at all. Essentially, the idea is that if you have that some statement is true for a 'base case' m and you suppose that the claim holds for some arbitrary n≥m, and show that this implies that it holds for n+1, then you've done it. Essentially, this is "bootstrapping." If you want, you can prove it rigorously, using the well ordering principle.

Well ordering principle: Any set of natural numbers has a smallest element. Prove the method works by contradiction.

Please note, however, that this question could have been answered by googling any of the following terms: "mathematical induction," "math induction" ect.