# What is induction, really?

Tags: logic, induction

I am usually confused about what is induction and what *proof* means in this context. As an example, take the proof of the sum of the first $n$-integers. First, we take the assertion $A_{n}$:

$$1+2+3+\dots + n\stackrel{?}{=}\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Then, if $r$ is an integer and if the previous statement is true, that is:

$$1+2+3+\dots + r=\frac{r(r+1)}{2}$$

Then by adding $(r+1)$ to both sides, gives me:

$$1+2+3+\dots + r+(r+1)=\frac{r(r+1)}{2}+(r+1)=\frac{r(r+1)+2(r+1)}{2}=\frac{(r+1)(r+2)}{2}$$

Which is precisely the statement $A_{r+1}$. If we test for the statement $A_1$, it is true. Then it is true for each natural number. For this, we had the requirements:

- $P(k)$ is true;
- $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$ for $n\geq k$.

> **Side question** In this example, it is not clear why $P(n)\implies P(n+1)$, that is: Why taking $\cfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and $\cfrac{r(r+1)}{2}$, making the substitutions $r:=r+1$, $n:=n+1$ and comparing the formulas show the truth of $A_n$? Why couldn't we use the same trick with any other formula not equivalent to $A_n$ and a similar result, that is: Have the proof I gave earlier as true and a proof that $1+2+3+\dots +n=F_n$ but $F_n\neq \cfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$?

Now, there is another *proof* for the same fact, take the following figure:

\begin{matrix}
 \circ & \circ   & \circ  \\ 
 \circ & \circ   & \\ 
 \circ &  & 
\end{matrix}

Now make a rotated copy of this figure:

\begin{matrix}
 &  &\bullet    \\ 
 & \bullet &\bullet  \\ 
 \bullet &\bullet   & \bullet 
\end{matrix}

And glue them together:

\begin{matrix}
 \circ & \circ   & \circ  \\ 
 \circ & \circ   & \bullet \\ 
 \circ & \bullet   & \bullet \\
 \bullet &\bullet   & \bullet 
\end{matrix}

In any way you glue them, the side of one rectangle will be $n+1$, the other will be $n$. Now we can see that for any $n$, we must have a square of area $n(n+1)$ and we want the area of the triangle. We can just do it as $\cfrac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

> Now here comes my problem: I don't actually feel that the first way proves this, but I feel that the second way does it. Also, with the first way, the formula appeared *magically*, we obtained it somewhere and are just *proving* it. But what is the actual meaning of *proving* here? Several months ago, I read a bit of Wittgenstein's *Tractatus Logico-Philosophicus*. There is an interesting item at it:
>
> $$\text{7. Whereof one cannot speak, thereof one must remain silent.}$$
>
> I guess that this hinted me for the first time what is the broader meaning of proving: I interpreted *being able to speak* as *being able to say something in a given language*. So in this case, it seems *we are being able to speak in logic* and induction is the ability to express a mathematical idea in the language of logic.  So, in the first case, we are *speaking* something and showing that the conclusion can be built coherently in logic. In the second case, we are not actually *speaking*, there is no well-defined language in which we are encoding the given propositions. With this, I've been able to discern that there are two different activities:
>
> - Being able to *see* something clearly. (Second proof)
> - Being able to *speak* something in a language, and if we can *speak* it, then we assume it is true. (First proof)
>
> Is this what induction is about?

Comment: @EricStucky You can start at the beginning: Why there isn't two different formulas for the sum of the integers?

Comment: Yes. The problem is that they are not actually *different*. I guess the question would be more like: Why aren't there two formulas that produce different sets: $\{ (x,f(x)) : x\in \mathbb{N} \}$ and yet, each formula *is* a formula for the sum of the first $n$ natural numbers?

Comment: We can produce two different sets, if you insist: $\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{2(n-2)}$ produces a different set from $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ because the former is undefined for $n=2$. But I don't think this is in the spirit of what you want. Are you asking why addition is well-defined?

Comment: No, I know this to be true. I guess it would be more like: Why is this whole thing - that is: The result that the formula is well defined for each $n$?

Comment: If addition is well-defined, then $\sum_{k=1}^n k$ exists. Maybe we can write down a simpler formula, maybe we can't, but it's definitely true that for any $n$, we do get some number. If we have two formulae $A(n)$ and $B(n)$ which both give that number, then $A(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n k$ and $B(n)=\sum_{k=1}^n k$, by definition. So $A(n)=B(n)$ because equality is transitive. Since this is true for all $n$, we have $A=B$ as functions, by definition.

Comment: Did you see http://math.stackexchange.com/q/448236/34930 ? If so, which point is not sufficiently explained in the answers?

Comment: $1 + 2 = 3, 1 + 2 + 3 = 6, 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 = 10$. You start to find a pattern, and you eventually come up that $1 + \dots + n = n(n+1)/2$, but you have to prove it. That's where it comes in.

Comment: @Nameless Yes. I already know this.

Comment: @celtschk I've seen, but it doesn't relate to my question. What is wrote there is already known by me. This is the standard answer everyone gives me when I ask something about induction. The core question is a little bit deeper than that.

Answer (score 2):

For your "side question": You're missing something absolutely essential about induction - the base case. In a proof by induction, one must show *not only* that $P(n) \Rightarrow P(n+1)$, but *also* that $P(1)$ holds (or $P(0)$, or $P(2)$, or wherever you want $P$ to start being true). The standard analogy is of a sequence of dominoes; by showing $P(n) \Rightarrow P(n + 1)$, we've shown that each domino is heavy enough to knock the next one down, but we don't know that any of them fall at all until we've shown that the *first* one does. We could use some random other formula in the induction step, sure - for example, we could do the following attempted induction:

Suppose that $1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + n = 1 + \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$. Adding $n + 1$ to both sides and simplifying, we obtain $1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + n + (n + 1) = 1 + \frac{(n+1)(n+2)}{2}$, which seems to complete the induction. The problem is that the missing step doesn't work - $A_1$, which in this case is the statement $1 = 1 + \frac{1(1+1)}{2}$, is false. Analogously, the first domino does not fall.

To respond to your main question: The second proof is not really a proof. You've successfully demonstrated that the claim is true when $n = 3$, and you've given a good reason to believe that it will be true for other values of $n$; but that's not "proof". How do we know that there's not some very large $n$ with just the right properties so that the "teeth" of your triangles don't quite line up right? The proof by induction, however, *is* a proof, because all that's required in order to be sure that no $n$ escapes it is the axiom "all natural numbers are reachable by induction".

The key difference is that the second "proof" hinges heavily on intuition; that's why it "feels" more natural to you, but that's also why it isn't proof - intuitions can be wrong, sometimes very badly wrong. The first proof uses only logic, which is as unarguable as we can reasonably expect to achieve.

As for the speak/see distinction, I sort of see (forgive the pun) what you're getting at, but it's not quite right. Just because we can "say" something clearly doesn't mean we assume it's true - there are plenty of obviously false things we can say clearly, like "$1+1=3$". But it *is* the case that we (or rather, mathematicians in general) do not consider something *proven* unless we can "speak" the proof clearly and correctly.

Comment: I'm not missing the base case. I wrote there: $P(k)$ is true.

Comment: I know the second proof is not a proof. I wrote it there.

Comment: Also, you can't say that $1+1=3$ if you assume Peano axioms.

Comment: @OppaHilbertStyle You wrote $P(k)$, but you seem to be ignoring it in your side question - maybe I'm misinterpreting. You did not write that the second proof is not a proof; you wrote "proof" in italics, which usually denotes emphasis, not doubt. And of course you can say $1 + 1 = 3$ under the Peano axioms; it just isn't true. Speech and truth are not the same thing in anyone's philosophy; falsehoods are perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Yes, I'm interpreting Wittgenstein's quote as something inside the universe of discourse and also as truth.

Comment: @OppaHilbertStyle My familiarity with Wittgenstein is limited, but I see no respect in which the quote in question says anything about the relationship between speech and truth, and as far as I know he doesn't say anything anywhere to the effect of "the only statements that can be made are true ones", which is what you seem to be saying. Maybe I'm misunderstanding your position - in that case, would it be possible for you to formulate it more clearly?

Comment: It doesn't say. ]I said that I'm interpreting that way.

Comment: @OppaHilbertStyle I see. Then I guess my response just boils down to: your interpretation doesn't make much sense, and certainly doesn't agree with what anyone else means by "speak" or "say". I suppose if by "say" you mean "provide a rigorous proof for", then yes, that is exactly the difference between those two "proofs".

Comment: Yes, what you wrote make sense. I guess I mixed those two notions in my mind but $1+1=3$ is *sayable* with Peano Axioms.